# PostGIS ST_Distance_Sphere speed-up

Tags: postgis, geoalchemy-2

I am trying to build a geocoding app on OSM data, that in regard to arbitrary location will return `points` within specified `radius`,  as well as `distances` to the points.

I have the following table:

```
id      parent_id   key       value         geometry
4821719 221252430   natural   water         POINT (-8.69802 40.60405)
3483776 3335087     leisure   sports_centre POINT (-8.71858 40.61685)
3483777 3335087     leisure   sports_centre POINT (-8.71608 40.61672)
```

all the geometries are points

I do it with the help of Python `geoalchemy2` package with the following expression:

```
query = session.query(Table,func.ST_Distance_Sphere(Table.geometry, arbitrary_point))\
               .filter(func.ST_Distance_Sphere(Table.geometry, arbitrary_point) < radius)
```

which translates to `sql` as:

```
SELECT table.id, table.parent_id, table.key, table.value, ST_AsEWKB(table.geometry) AS 
geometry, 
ST_Distance_Sphere(table.geometry, ST_GeomFromWKB(:ST_GeomFromWKB_1, :ST_GeomFromWKB_2)) AS 
"ST_Distance_Sphere_1" 
FROM table 
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(table.geometry, ST_GeomFromWKB(:ST_GeomFromWKB_3, :ST_GeomFromWKB_4)) < :ST_Distance_Sphere_2
```

the returned result is like:

```
id  parent_id   key            value          geometry                 ST_Distance_Sphere_1
2   3788923     natural        water          POINT (-0.47833 52.25222)  9906.627366
5   3865117     leisure       sports_centre   POINT (-0.50365 52.16449)  0.333864
9   4082699     addr:country    GB            POINT (-0.49252 52.16019)  896.977083
12  4082701     addr:country    GB            POINT (-0.49220 52.16020)  915.175355
16  4082703     addr:country    GB            POINT (-0.49205 52.16015)  927.182032
```

the query takes long time to execute, so tried to add index with

```
CREATE INDEX geo ON table USING GIST ( geometry );
```

but it did not help at all

so I tried to remove this index, having the `drop INDEX` never finish.

I need the ways to speed-up the query.

Also, as well quering individual locations, I will need query
large arrays of locations at a time.

I am entirely new to PostgreSQL.

`_____edit_____`

`EXPLAIN` in `presence of the index` returns the following:

```
[('Gather  (cost=1000.00..3863720.18 rows=2741158 width=68)',),
 ('  Workers Planned: 2',),
 ('  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on osm  (cost=0.00..3588604.38 rows=1142149 width=68)',),
 ("        Filter: (st_distance_sphere(geometry, 
'0101000020E6100000BEDEFDF15E6D21C0EF74E789E74E4440'::geometry) < 
'2000'::double precision)",)]
```

'EXPLAIN' having the `index dropped`:

```
[('Gather  (cost=1000.00..3863720.18 rows=2741158 width=68)',),
 ('  Workers Planned: 2',),
 ('  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on osm  (cost=0.00..3588604.38 rows=1142149 
width=68)',),
 ("        Filter: (st_distance_sphere(geometry, 
'0101000020E6100000BEDEFDF15E6D21C0EF74E789E74E4440'::geometry) < 
'2000'::double precision)",)]
```

Comment: we need to see the output of EXPLAIN on the query both with and without the index

Comment: @IanTurton, I am not sure that is what you expect to see, but I havermanaged to get the following. That is in the presence of the index. I can not quickly query the table without index, as it takes forever to remove for some reason: 
    [('Gather  (cost=1000.00..3863720.18 rows=2741158 width=68)',), ('  Workers 
    Planned: 2',), ('  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on osm  (cost=0.00..3588604.38 
    rows=1142149 width=68)',), ("        Filter: (st_distance_sphere(geometry, 
    '0101000020E6100000BEDEFDF15E6D21C0EF74E789E74E4440'::geometry) < 
    '2000'::double precision)",)]

Comment: I have managed to drop the index and surprisingly the EXPLAIN outputs seem identical to me

Comment: Nothing suprising about that; your query cannot use any (spatial) index, since there is no invocating filter condition. Right now, you ask PG to traverse the whole table (`Seq scan`) and calculate distances between all points and the given EWKT geometry. You want to use `ST_DWithin(geometry::GEOGRAPHY, <EWKT_Geom>::GEOGRAPHY, <distance>)` and have an index `USING GIST (CAST(geometry AS GEOGRAPHY))` in place. On a sidenote: `ST_Distance_Sphere` is a deprecated signature, use `ST_DistanceSphere`.